# How to initialise an unsafe pointer in C# and convert it to a byte[]?

Tags: c#, pointers, embedded, arm

I put a post up yesterday, How does one create structures for C# originally written in C++.

Thank you for your responses.

I'm trying, without much success, to use DeviceIOControl on an ARM platform running WinCE 6.0 and .NET Compact framework 2.0  All I am trying to achieve is the control of a port pin and it's proving to be a nightmare.

The following is the PInvoke declaration:

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint = "DeviceIoControl", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool DeviceIoControlCE(int hDevice,
                                             int dwIoControlCode,
                                             byte[] lpInBuffer,
                                             int nInBufferSize,
                                             byte[] lpOutBuffer,
                                             int nOutBufferSize,
                                             ref int lpBytesReturned,
                                             IntPtr lpOverlapped);
```

The PInvoke declaration suggests a byte[] may be passed to it simply.  Surely it's an easy matter to write the values to each member of a structure, convert it to an array of bytes and pass it to the dll.

I have the following:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]  
    public struct pio_desc 
    {
        unsafe byte* pin_name;      //Length???
        public uint pin_number;     //4 bytes
        public uint default_value;  //4 bytes
        public byte attribute;      //1 byte
        public uint pio_type;       //4 bytes
    }
```

and

pio_desc PA13 = new pio_desc();

So surely now it's a matter of doing something like:

```
PA13.pin_number = AT91_PIN_PA13;      //Length 4 bytes
PA13.default_value = 0;               //Length 4 bytes
PA13.attribtue = PIO_DEFAULT;         //Length 1 byte
PA13.pio_type = PIO_OUTPUT;           //Length 4 bytes
```

and to convert (pin_number for example) to a byte[]:

```
byte[] temp = BitConverter.GetBytes(PA13.pin_number); //uints are 4 bytes wide
        byteArray[++NumberOfChars] = temp[0];
        byteArray[++NumberOfChars] = temp[1];
        byteArray[++NumberOfChars] = temp[2];
        byteArray[++NumberOfChars] = temp[3];     //Will need to check on Endianess
```

Questions:

In the structure PA13, how do I initialise the unsafe pointer pin_name? The author of the driver notes that this is not used, presumably by his driver. Will Windows need this to be some value?

PA13.pin_name = ??????

Then, how do I convert this pointer to a byte to fit into my byte[] array to be passed to DeviceIOControl?

I've become quite disappointed and frustrated at how difficult it is to change the voltage level of a port pin - I've been struggling with this problem for days now.  Because I come from a hardware background, I think it's going to be easier (and less eligant) for me to implement IO control on another controller and to pass control data to it via a COM port.

Thanks again for any (simple) assistance.

Comment: Can you paste the unmanaged structure definition?  It looks like `pin_name` is actually supposed to be a C-style string, since a literal port of the struct would have come from `char *pin_name`.  If that is the case, you can use `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pin_name;` in the struct.

Comment: Thanks for the interest! The unmananged structure is: struct pio_desc {
 const char *pin_name;   /* Pin Name */
 unsigned int pin_num;   /* Pin number */
 unsigned int dft_value; /* Default value for outputs */
 unsigned char attribute;
 enum pio_type type;
};        I wish to replace the enum with an int or byte datatype.  According to a technical note I have about this struct, the author says that the Pin Name is not used.  Seems odd to include it then, but I think that referencing a pin happens by a number instead.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do a few different things here.  First, replace this member:

```
unsafe byte* pin_name;      //Length???
```

with:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pin_name;
```

Then replace the in/out buffers in the P/Invoke declaration from `byte[]` to `IntPtr`.  Then you can use this code to convert the data:

```
pio_desc PA13;
// Set the members of PA13...

IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
try {
    var size = Marshal.SizeOf(PA13);
    ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

    Marshal.StructureToPtr(PA13, ptr, false);

    // Your P/Invoke call goes here.
    // size will be the "nInBufferSize" argument
    // ptr will be the "lpInBuffer" argument
} finally {
    if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero) {
        Marshal.DestroyStructure(ptr, typeof(pio_desc));
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! I've implemented this code, however, what would I pass to the int nInBufferSize parameter?  I've tried a few things and none have worked: got a 'Not Supported Exception' error back.

Comment: You would pass `Marshal.SizeOf(PA13)`.  Let me update the code.  Also, can you clarify which line you get that exception from?

Comment: I get the exception on ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(PA13));  Is it normal to battle for so long with this DeviceIOControl function? There seems to be many people asking questions about this. Thanks again for your help as I'm at my rope's end now. One other thing that didn't seem to work: there's no DestroyStructure method available in the menu on my PC.  I'm running .NET compact which may be the problem with this whole thing.

Comment: @Gary: Are you using the compact framework or some non-standard .NET environment?  AllocHGlobal and SizeOf should be supported.  Can you clarify whether AllocHGlobal or SizeOf is throwing the exception, and what .NET platform you are on?

Comment: @Gary: MSDN claims that AllocHGlobal/SizeOf/DestroyStructure are all implemented on .NET 3.5 CF, but not .NET 2.0 CF.

Comment: Yeah, this code is not going to work for you since the 2.0 CF lacks quite a lot of methods on the Marshal class.  Is the 3.5 CF an option for you?

Comment: It may be!  I'll need to get hold of VS2008 in that case, I don't think that VS2005 supports .NET 3.5.  Are there any other options available to get around this issue?  I have a C++ example showing how they use the various structures etc. Could this assist in solving this issue? G

Comment: @Gary: Well, there's always the `byte[]` option you were proposing, where you marshal the data yourself.  If you like pain, that's one way to go.

Comment: I've been experiencing pain on this issue for that last week!  I'm actually quite disgusted at the complexity of managing hardware from C#.  I'm doing a masters in electronics and am now stuck trying to toggle a port pin to control a modem module!

Comment: @Gary: You might try Hans' solution too.  For some reason I didn't think of letting the P/Invoke layer do the marshaling.. d'oh.

Comment: Thanks for the chat!  It's been a very long day, so it's time to stop. Would you mind if I came back to you on this issue in the next couple of days?  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @Gary: Not at all.  Good luck!

Comment: Hi cdhowie, are you there?  OK, I've upgraded to .NET Compact Framework 3.5.  It seems that there are now more marshalling methods available.  I'm still battling with the problem of getting IO working smoothly.  There has been one useful development that a port pin now flips, but irritatingly, the DLL or something crahses, freezing the entire board!  The DeviceIOControl function returns true and Error 87, which is an Invalid Parameter message. Stuck again.... Any thoughts on this? Thanks!

Comment: @Gary: Perhaps the struct alignment/packing needs to be explicitly specified?

Answer (score 1):

You can make this a lot easier by lying about the [DllImport] declaration.  Just declare the lpInBuffer argument as the structure type, the pinvoke marshaller will convert it to a pointer anyway.  Thus:

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint = "DeviceIoControl", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool SetOutputPin(IntPtr hDevice,
                                             int dwIoControlCode,
                                             ref pio_desc lpInBuffer,
                                             int nInBufferSize,
                                             IntPtr lpOutBuffer,
                                             int nOutBufferSize,
                                             out int lpBytesReturned,
                                             IntPtr lpOverlapped);
```

Using IntPtr for lpOutBuffer because the driver probably doesn't return anything.  Pass IntPtr.Zero.  Same idea with the structure.  If the field isn't used then simply declare it as an IntPtr:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]  
public struct pio_desc 
{
    public IntPtr pin_name;     // Leave at IntPtr.Zero
    public uint pin_number;     //4 bytes
    public uint default_value;  //4 bytes
    public byte attribute;      //1 byte
    public uint pio_type;       //4 bytes
}
```

Be careful about the Packing property, it makes a difference here because of the byte sized field.  You may need 1 but that's just a guess without knowing anything about the driver.  If you have working C code then test the value of sizeof(pio_desc) and compare with Marshal.SizeOf().  Pass Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(pio_desc)) as the nInBufferSize argument.  If you would have posted the C declarations then this would have been easier to answer accurately.

Comment: He he!!  Thanks for the response!!  I'll take a look at this too, while I'm deciding on what to do next if this function doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Declare lpInBuffer and lpOutBuffer as IntPtr. Initialize them using Marshal.AllocHGlobal (don't forget to release them with Marshal.FreeHGlobal in the end). Fill these buffer and read it using different Marshal.Copy overloads.